# Why does my listview display the button and edittext as well?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My listview display all componenents.
But I want to display only messages.

Here the pic of whatit looks like...

[Loooks very messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ZbQ.png)
[The pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFpEa.jpg)

The TextView(source of message) and Button were repeated below the next message.if there is possibility that I can se that function without a textview I think it would be better.I mean if that list view receives messages directly from the URL (googlespreadsheet).

Here those are my scripts.Thanks in advance

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Message">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mesaj"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/listviewmes" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mesajtext"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="Mesajiniz..."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sendbutton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mesaj"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/mesajtext"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mesajtext"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewmes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bck"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>




public class Message extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseUser fuser;
FirebaseDatabase database;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
EditText et;
TextView tv;
ProgressDialog pd;
ListView lview;
ListAdapter adaptery;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Button sendbtn;
    Toolbar toolbar;


    sendbtn = findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    //tv = findViewById(R.id.mesaj);
    et = findViewById(R.id.mesajtext);
    lview = findViewById(R.id.listviewmes);
    getItems();



    sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addItemToSheet();
            et.getText().clear();

        }
    });
}`

`private void addItemToSheet() {
    final String mesaj = et.getText().toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "MY URL SEND TO GOOGLE SHEET",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();
            parmas.put("action", "addItem");
            parmas.put("mesaj", mesaj);

            return parmas;
        }
    };
    int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}


public void sendMessage(View v) {
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String stuuid = uuid.toString();
    String mesaj = et.getText().toString();


}

private void getItems() {

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "please wait", false, true);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "MY URL MESSAGES GET FROM GOOGLE SHEET",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    parseItems(response);

                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );
    int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds

    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void parseItems(String jsonResposnce) {


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String>Mesajlar=new ArrayList<String>();



    try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResposnce);
        JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");


        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String mesaj = jo.getString("mesaj");


            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
            item.put("mesaj", mesaj);

            list.add(item);


        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    `adaptery = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.activity_message,
            new String[]{"mesaj"},new int[]{R.id.mesaj, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list});


    lview.setAdapter(adaptery);
    pd.dismiss();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

user RecyclerView instead of ListView (ListView don't free memory but RecyclerView is a ListView that is work better) and then in the Adapter Class you have a class named MyViewHolder that extend from RecyclerView.ViewHolder
in this class you will have all of your view in the layout you want to set to the RecyclerView 
in the Adapetr Class you have a function named : onBindViewHolder and has an input of your MyViewHolder , you can hide the button there

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i)
        {
             if(condition)
                myViewHolder.button.setVisibilty(View.GONE); 
        }
```

here is the myViewHolder

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView txt;
    Button btn;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        txt= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        btn= itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn)
    }
}
```

i don't know why every row has a button and a EditText in you code , but if the EditText is fro URL and button for confirm the operation(loading data from URL) you don't need to add those in your list layout ! you should add one button and one EditText above of your activity and set a RecyclerView below them